# Jquery Callback function - "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, callback

i've a jquery (UI) App here where the whole JQuery Code gets a little bit messy, so i started to think around how to structure this in a little bit fancier way... i read a blog post somewhere, that "oop" - in a java way can be achieved by doing some kind of this:

```
function RangeSelector(product_id) {
    this.product_id = product_id;
    this.start_point = "#from_" + product_id;
    this.end_point = "#to_" + product_id;
}
RangeSelector.prototype.myFunction = function() { }
```

the whole code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/fPNxqX9R).

My Range Selector "Class" should hold two jquery ui [datetimepickers](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) that are responsible to let the user select a date time range for a shop where you can rent products

The problem that i currently have is the following: the date time pickers get callback functions ("unavailableFrom", "unavailableTo") where i'd like to do some specific things and then call a generic "unavailable" to function.
The error message is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.unavailable(date)')
```

I looked about that with firebug and it seems, that "this" not my object of the RangeSelector, but the HTML Element on what the datetimepicker is working. 
My Question is: how can i access this method "unavailable"?

By the way, i tell you the whole story in here, because i don't think, that the structure that i chose here is the right way to go. How do you handle these kind of things, where you have more than one html elements that have a common meaning and you would like to aggregate them?

Comment: if i understand you well you need to bind the methods to a context , this in javascript is not the instance , but the context in which the function is being called. That's why javascript is so difficult , because it uses keywords that have nothing to do with the definition one usually gives them , so you can create a function bind  : function _bind(_function,_context){
    return function(){
        return _function.apply(_context,arguments);
    }
}​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to set `this` to a different value, you can use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) to do that. (Or in an ES5-enabled environment, you can use the new [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5) function.) `proxy` accepts a function and value to use for `this`, and returns a function that will call the original with `this` set to that value.

So for instance, suppose you have your `RangeSelector` and you want `click` to trigger `myFunction` on a specific instance:

```
var r = new RangeSelector(/* ...args...*/);
$("some_selector").click($.proxy(r.myFunction, r));
```

Now, when `r.myFunction` is called, within the call, `this` will be a reference to the `r` object. (If you need to know which DOM element was clicked, have `myFunction` accept the `event` argument that jQuery passes it, and use `event.target`.)

For completeness, the above using `Function#bind` (if the browser supports ES5 features, or you've included an ES5 shim [since `Function#bind` is shim-able]):

```
var r = new RangeSelector(/* ...args...*/);
$("some_selector").click(r.myFunction.bind(r));
```

More to explore (on my blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

The jQuery UI `datepicker`'s `onSelect` is a bit of a pain, because they don't give you the `event` object and so you don't have access to `event.target`. Your best bet there is probably a closure that passes the element on:

```
var r = new RangeSelector(/* ...args...*/);
$("some_selector")..datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        return r.myFunction(dateText, inst, this);
    }
});
```

...where `myFunction` accepts `dateText`, `inst`, and `element` arguments.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/unaguh) | [source](http://jsbin.com/unaguh/edit)

That works because the function we're assigning to `onSelect` is a closure over the environment containing the `r` variable.

Closures are frequently misunderstood; FWIW, another blog entry: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: thx, that works great, until i realize, that in another function "onSelect", i need access to the range selector object as well as the actual datepicker html element object - can you give me a little example of this: "(If you need to know which DOM element was clicked, have myFunction accept the event argument that jQuery passes it, and use event.target.)" ?

Comment: @MarioDavid: Ah, jQuery UI's datepicker `onSelect` is a pain. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` is changing scope on you, so it doesn't mean the same thing in different places like you expect it to. I would recommend that you explicitly pass the element that you are working with around in functions, and reference that element directly, instead of trying to discern scope with `this`.

Comment: ok, that would be the alternative that i already thought about, but it wasn't clear to me, how a pass in any kind of object to a callback method, when doing something like this: "beforeShowDay: this.unavailableFrom" - is it just: "beforeShowDay: this.unavailableFrom(myVar)" ?